# media library and video

Tags: video, sitecore

I am currently looking to integrate JW Player into a sitecore site. I have it working fine when I statically give the player the url of a video in my media library. The bit I'm struggling with is now making it a field in sitecore content so a content person could upload and choose a video from the media library.

Basically what i want to to is use a field that just give me the url of the video so i can put it in the jw player snippet, so something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "<sc:link Field="link" runat="server">",
        image: "/uploads/example.jpg",
    });
</script>
```

But that doesn't work obviously...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<sc:link />` control in Javascript is indeed not going to work. You need to create the correct Url to your movie with serverside code (use the Sitecore LinkManager).

There are several ways to get the url to your javascript. You could pass the link as a parameter to your Javascript or use inline code statements like `<%= VideoUrlVariable %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "<asp:Literal ID="litMediaUrl" runat="server" />",
        image: "/uploads/example.jpg",
    });
</script>
```

Then in your code-behind you retrieve the LinkField url value:

```
LinkField linkField = item.Fields["your_linkfield_name"];
litMediaUrl.Text = linkField.Url;
```

Maybe you need to retrieve the linked Item first and then get the URL of that (not sure about that). In that case you would do:

```
litMediaUrl.Text = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(linkField.TargetItem);
```